# how to integrate Cassandra with Hadoop to take advantage of Hive

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, hive, bigdata

It is almost 3 days that I've been looking for a solution at year 2015 to integrate Cassandra on Hadoop and lots of resources on the net are outdated or vanished from the net and the Datastax Enterprise offers no free of charge solution for such integration.

What are the options for doing such? I want to use Hive query language to get data from my Cassandra and I think the first step is to integrate the Cassandra with Hadoop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest (but also paid option) is to use Datastax Enterprise packaging of C* with Hadoop + Hive. This provides an automatic connection and registration of Hive tables with C* and includes and setups up a Hadoop execution platform if you need one.
http://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-enterprise

The second easiest way is to utilize Spark instead. The Spark Cassandra Connector is open source and allows HiveQL to be used to access C* tables. This is done running on Spark as an execution platform instead of Hadoop but has similar (if not better) performance.

With this solution I would standup a stand alone Spark Cluster (since you don't have an existing hadoop infra) and then use the spark-sql-thrift server to run queries against C* tables.
https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector

There are other options but these are the ones I am most familiar with (and conflict of interest notice, also develop :D )